# How to extract the target element of internal links with pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I'm rendering PDFs of academic papers with [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). These papers include internal links to references at the bottom of the PDF. Given an anchor (e.g. #first.ref),

I'd like to extract its target element, however, I can't find that element (id) at all in the HTML content. Can I do that with pdf.js instead somehow?

Example:
This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476v2.pdf) has some links (the green text below) to references at the end of the document. Each link has an anchor and I'd like to extract the target html element of that anchor.

[image]

I'm creating the pdf object with the following code:

```
this.linkService = new PDFLinkService();
this.viewer = new PDFViewer({
  container: this.containerNode,
  enhanceTextSelection: true,
  removePageBorders: true,
  linkService: this.linkService,
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code we can see. This is too broad of a question.

Comment: @shadoe2020 I think it's more related to pdf.js code than to mine, but anyway I added more details. I hope it helps.

Comment: where is your HTML or link to a page where your ID is missing.

Comment: What do you mean? The link and the target are both part of the PDF